# cannot listen song n° 7025067 with deezer js sdk

Tags: javascript, deezer

I have a problem with the stream of the song at the URL http://www.deezer.com/track/7025067 (Italy)

no audio, while the song infos are correctly retrieved.

the json response, when playing the track, is as follows:

```
{
"error": [],
"results": {
    "data": [
        {
            "ALB_ID": "647144",
            "ALB_PICTURE": "e5ea47abf640c983b93deaa46e595fc4",
            "ALB_TITLE": "No Surrender: Platinum Edition",
            "ART_ID": "219",
            "ART_NAME": "Kane",
            "DATE_START": "0000-00-00",
            "DATE_START_PREMIUM": "0000-00-00",
            "DURATION": "185",
            "FILESIZE": "2969214",
            "FILESIZE_MP3_128": "2969214",
            "FILESIZE_MP3_256": "0",
            "FILESIZE_MP3_320": "7420993",
            "MD5_ORIGIN": "bfbb6f909a056a130cefb9d661074eae",
            "MEDIA_VERSION": "0",
            "SMARTRADIO": "1",
            "SNG_ID": "7025067",
            "SNG_TITLE": "No Surrender",
            "STATUS": 1,
            "S_MOD": 0,
            "S_PREMIUM": 0,
            "URL_REWRITING": "kane",
            "RIGHTS": {},
            "PROVIDER_ID": "4"
        }
    ],
    "count": 1,
    "total": 1
}}
```

if I try to play directly from deezer website I cannot listen anyway. this is the json caught

```
{
    "error": [],
    "results": {
        "data": [
            {
                "ALB_ID": "647144",
                "ALB_PICTURE": "e5ea47abf640c983b93deaa46e595fc4",
                "ALB_TITLE": "No Surrender: Platinum Edition",
                "ARRANGER": "",
                "ARTISTS": [
                    {
                        "ART_ID": "219",
                        "ROLE_ID": "0",
                        "ART_NAME": "Kane",
                        "ART_PICTURE": "",
                        "SMARTRADIO": "1",
                        "RANK": "313324"
                    }
                ],
                "ART_ID": "219",
                "ART_NAME": "Kane",
                "AUTHOR": "",
                "BPM": "89",
                "COMPOSER": "",
                "CREATIVE_COMMON": "0",
                "DATE_START": "0000-00-00",
                "DATE_START_PREMIUM": "0000-00-00",
                "DIGITAL_RELEASE_DATE": "2010-09-24",
                "DISK_NUMBER": "1",
                "DURATION": "185",
                "EXPLICIT_LYRICS": "0",
                "FILESIZE": "2969214",
                "FILESIZE_MP3_128": "2969214",
                "FILESIZE_MP3_256": "0",
                "FILESIZE_MP3_320": "7420993",
                "FULL_PATH_ORIGIN": "/data/music/import/indexed/lbl_universal/2010/2010-09-01/3000001995339/00602527520704_3000001995339/UMG_audtrk_00602527520704_01_001_67.mp3",
                "GENRE_ID": "10",
                "GRID": "",
                "INDEXATION_DATE": "2010-09-01 18:13:21",
                "ISRC": "NLCD40900001",
                "KEYWORD": "",
                "LABEL_ID": "17732",
                "LANG": "0",
                "LYRICS": "",
                "MD5_ORIGIN": "bfbb6f909a056a130cefb9d661074eae",
                "MEDIA_VERSION": "0",
                "NOTE": "0",
                "ORIGIN": "0",
                "PERFORMER": "",
                "PHYSICAL_RELEASE_DATE": "2010-09-24",
                "PROVIDER_ID": "4",
                "PUID": "bfbb6f909a056a130cefb9d661074eae",
                "RANK": "279074",
                "RIGHTS": {},
                "SMARTRADIO": "1",
                "SNG_ID": "7025067",
                "SNG_ID_NEW": "0",
                "SNG_STATUS": "1",
                "SNG_TITLE": "No Surrender",
                "SONY_ID": "00602527520704_NLCD4",
                "STATUS": 1,
                "S_ALC": 0,
                "S_MOD": 0,
                "S_PREMIUM": 0,
                "S_WIDGET": 0,
                "TRACK_NUMBER": "1",
                "UPDATE_DATE": "2013-09-27 05:05:27",
                "URL_REWRITING": "kane",
                "USER_ID": 0,
                "VERSION": ""
            }
        ],
        "count": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

there're some others similar songs with this problem. what can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know why. I just found that visiting the deezer api [and checking the json](http://api.deezer.com/track/7025067) Italy (IT) is not in the available countries array.

```
{
    "id": 7025067,
    "readable": false,
    "title": "No Surrender",
    "isrc": "NLCD40900001",
    "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/7025067",
    "duration": 185,
    "track_position": 1,
    "disk_number": 1,
    "rank": 279074,
    "explicit_lyrics": false,
    "preview": "http://cdn-preview-b.deezer.com/stream/bfbb6f909a056a130cefb9d661074eae-0.mp3",
    "bpm": 89,
    "gain": -7.05,
    "available_countries": [
        "NL"
    ],
    "artist": {
        "id": 219,
        "name": "Kane",
        "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/219",
        "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/artist/219/image",
        "radio": true
    },
    "album": {
        "id": 647144,
        "title": "No Surrender: Platinum Edition",
        "link": "http://www.deezer.com/album/647144",
        "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/album/647144/image",
        "release_date": "2010-09-24"
    },
    "type": "track"
}
```